# Mismo campo distinta tabla, Sin relacion de tablas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo dos tablas con distinto nombre  pero los campos son iguales,
quiero hacer una consulta  que solo me agarre el nombre de una y me arroje los registros de los dos. El problema  que ninguna de las dos tienen relación.
alguna sugerencia

`SELECT ID_TipoTramiteNotarial,ID_Subsidiaria,ID_EstadoSolicitud from GC_SolicitudFeHecho
SELECT ID_TipoTramiteNotarial,ID_Subsidiaria,ID_EstadoSolicitud from GC_SolicitudAdjudicacion`

Estas son mis tablas con campos iguales pero distintas tablas.
Espero me puedan ayudar se los agradezco.

Comment: Creo que con UNION ALL podes hacer lo que queres. Si es que entendi bien, solo queres poner los valores de una debajo de la otra. Aca podes ver la explicacion en MSDN https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 y aca (en ingles) podes correr ejemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Suena a que tengas que usar la cláusula UNION de SQL... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 3):

Usa un UNION ALL para devolver los registros de ambas. Ni siquiera necesitan tener los mismos campos, vale con que los campos que devuelve la consulta sean compatibles.

En este caso sería algo como

```
SELECT ID_TipoTramiteNotarial,ID_Subsidiaria,ID_EstadoSolicitud from GC_SolicitudFeHecho
UNION ALL
SELECT ID_TipoTramiteNotarial,ID_Subsidiaria,ID_EstadoSolicitud from GC_SolicitudAdjudicacion
```

Para usar campos compatibles con distinto nombre puedes usar alias, simplemente, o si no te va a coger el encabezado de la primera tabla. Para usar alias sería algo como

```
SELECT ID_SolicitudFeHecho AS ID_Solicitud, ID_TipoTramiteNotarial,ID_Subsidiaria,ID_EstadoSolicitud from GC_SolicitudFeHecho
UNION ALL
SELECT ID_SolicitudAdjudicacion AS ID_Solicitud, ID_TipoTramiteNotarial,ID_Subsidiaria,ID_EstadoSolicitud from GC_SolicitudAdjudicacion
```

He puesto el alias también en la segunda tabla por completitud, pero puedes probar que no hace falta, debería valer con ponerlo solo en la primera.

Comment: disculpa esto me surgió apenas, si quiero agregar un campo diferente en ambas  tablas me podria dar una idea ejemplo:     


 SELECT ID_SolicitudFeHecho, ID_TipoTramiteNotarial,ID_Subsidiaria,ID_EstadoSolicitud from GC_SolicitudFeHecho


UNION ALL
SELECT ID_SolicitudAdjudicacion, ID_TipoTramiteNotarial,ID_Subsidiaria,ID_EstadoSolicitud from GC_SolicitudAdjudicacion